# Making a gradient from a set of solid-filled shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, gradient-mesh

I want to make mesh gradient from an abstract figure. The original figure made by adding an abstract solid figure as a Clipping Mask to a camouflage vector pattern. The resulted figure attached in raster.

My idea is to make a gradient transformation inside this figure, to transform sharp boundaries between each two different color regions into gradients.

Maybe, there are some tutorials available on the Internet, but I cannot find anything still.

My figure is:
[image: Original vector image preview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possiblity is to blur all and then cut your shape. the result would be something like this:

[image]

All transitions between areas are now gradients.

If you have a visio of non-blurred sharp looking result that still is gradients, the sharpness can be created by adding some other texture that's not blurred. A couple of examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]